# Task.Yield(); SyncAction(); vs Task.Run(()=>SyncAction());

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

Let's say I wanted to just quickly make the following method run asynchronously:

```
ResultType SynchronousCode(ParamType x)
{
     return SomeLongRunningWebRequest(x);
}
```

What would be the difference in how the following two code samples are executed/scheduled?

```
async Task<ResultType> AsynchronousCode(ParamType x)
{
    return await Task.Run(() => SomeLongRunningWebRequest(x));
}
```

Compared to:

```
async Task<ResultType> AsynchronousCode(ParamType x)
{
    await Task.Yield();
    return SomeLongRunningWebRequest(x);
}
```

I understand that the Task.Yield() call will ensure that the thread immediately returns to the caller, and that Task.Run() will definitely schedule the code to run somewhere on the ThreadPool, but do both of these methods effectively make the method async? Let's assume for this question that we are on the default SynchronizationContext.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While both options are bad, there is a difference (important in GUI applications): after `Task.Yield` returns, the rest of the method will be dispatched back to original `SynchronizationContext`. If you ran that from UI thread, your long running operation will be executed on UI thread, thus freezing it. So if your intention was to avoid UI blocking - `Task.Yield` won't work. With `Task.Run` that won't happen.

Comment: So if we are on the default SynchronizationContext, there is no difference at all?

Comment: @Dev2345 as long as you don't have a funky task scheduler overriding the default scheduler ...., yes, I think...

Comment: I suppose on default context it will make no difference. But I can hardly imagine you will do that this way anywhere except UI application (to avoid blocking)

Comment: Why exactly are you saying this is bad? Is there a better way to accomplish what this code is here? I understand that I would want SomeLongRunningWebRequest to be async itself, but assuming I don't have that option, is there a better way?

Comment: To answer that I suppose we need to know more about what you are trying to do. But basically yes, SomeLongRunningWebRequest should be async itself. Maybe if you want to run multiple such requests in parallel, and you have absolutely no way to make long running method async - you can use Task.Run.

Comment: Calling `Task.Yeild()` is more bad because you have something that you know will run on a background thread vs something that will run on a background thread, but only if you call it in just the right way. The reason both options are bad is creating async wrappers for sync functions [is a anti-pattern anyway](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/24/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/), you should not be doing it. Let the caller call `Task.Run(` on `SynchronousCode` if they need to.

Comment: @Evk There are other situations, such as if I would want to run this method in parallel

Comment: Yes I think I mention exactly this situation in my comment. But then - no need to make method "async" - just call Task.Run on synchronous version, as mentioned by Scott above.